# mediaelement.js: Getting videos to work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, expressionengine, mediaelement.js

This seems like a common issue but I have not found any questions that have an answer marked so thought I would create one in hopes of finding a solution.

My videos work fine in Chrome and Safari but when it comes to Firefox it doesnt display at all.. my CMS is ExpressionEngine if that helps any.  Does anyone have experience with this?

The inserted code for the video on the page:

```
<video width="640" height="360" preload="none" controls="controls" poster="http://site.com/img.jpeg" id="player1" type="video/mp4" src="http://site.com/content/videos/videotest(360p_H.264-AAC).mp4" tabindex="0"></video>
```

Comment: what is the video type? and post some of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purposes replace your video tag with these videos (from mediaelement's website)

```
<video id="player1" width="540" height="303" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="
http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="
http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="
http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

If the above code works in FF, then the problem is related to video compression for FF. Like you I've had some problems with mediaelement.js but it turned out it was my videos that weren't well compresseed.

Comment: This did end up working for me, I was trying to test by uploading videos that were on youtube to this site but I'll test with some of the clients videos to see if they work.  So I guess my issue was the same to yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that you have the correct MIME types setup on your server.

You can add these to the .htaccess file,

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

See http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation for more informaition.

Comment: i tried adding this but I'm still having issues.. thakns though !

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the wrong convertion from mp4 with the MIRO Converter.
If I used "Other -> mp4" it doesn't work.
If I used "Apple -> iPad" I got the correct mp4 file and it runs!